# Is knapsack a Linear Programming problem?

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, knapsack-problems

Since Knapsack give Optimal solution as LP so is it also a LP or not ?

Comment: How knapsack gives optimal solution as LP?

Comment: it gives Optimal solution by DP method. not by LP method.

Comment: Knapsack problem is NP-hard and can be formulated as an integer linear program. Linear programming is in P so more probably knapsack isn't a linear programming problem.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean when you say "X is a linear programming problem"? Do you mean "X reduces to linear programming / can be solved using linear programming"?

Answer (score 2):

The knapsack problem can be modelled as a mixed integer program (MIP) and the linear-programming relaxation of this model can be solved. The linear relaxation does not give a solution to the problem, but it will provide an upper bound to the solution of the knapsack problem (equivalent to a solution of the MIP) which helps the MIP solver in its quest to find the optimal integer solution.